# Count down timer not stop at 00:00:00:00:00

Tags: ios, timestamp, nstimer, nscalendar

I’m using Xcode 5.1 and have a count down timer which does not stop at 00:00:00:00 and keeps counting down to negative numbers please can you help the code is displayed below:

Please note that  datelabel.text is where the timer will appears.

```
-(void)updatelabel{
    NSCalendar *calender= [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    int units = NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *components = [calender components:units  fromDate:[NSDate date] toDate:destinationdate options:1];

    [datelabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%c %d%c %d%c %d%c %d%c", [components month], 'm',[components day], 'd',[components hour], 'h',[components minute], 'm',[components second], 's']];
}


if ([store.offer isEqual:@"No"] || [store.offerexp isEqual:@"3600"] ) {
    datelabel.text =@"xx";
} else {
    destinationdate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:store.offerexp.intValue];

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updatelabel) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    NSLog(@"destination%@",destinationdate);
}

NSTimeInterval TimeStamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop the timer when `destinationdate` has been reached.

```
- (void)updateLabel:(NSTimer *)timer {
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    if ([now compare:destinationdate] != NSOrderedAscending) {
        NSCalendar *calender= [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
        int units = NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
        NSDateComponents *components = [calender components:units  fromDate:now toDate:destinationdate options:1];

        [datelabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dm %dd %dh %dm %ds", [components month], [components day], [components hour], [components minute], [components second]]];
    } else {
        [timer invalidate];
        dateLabel.text = @"0m 0d 0h 0m 0s";
    }
}
```

And update the timer selector to be `@selector(updateLabel:)` instead of `@selector(updatelabel)`.

Also note that the format string can include the time units directly.

Note - I might have the `if` check backwards. It might need to be `NSOrderedDescending`.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response maddy, Ive updated my code with your suggestions the timer label just displays XX and does not appear in the label at all for the countdown period specified.

Comment: please ignore the above comment the code loads but then crashes as view appear saying "updatelabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance".